# AJAX is not correctly sending POST variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm writing a basic application in AJAX that need to send some data over POST to a php page.

The problem I'm getting here is that the php page is not correctly receiving data in the $_POST: if I try to print its content I get an empty array.

Can you help me point out the problem?

```
// global variables
var sendReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();


// get the browser dependent XMLHttpRequest object
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    else { 
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 
        'Status: Error while creating XmlHttpRequest Object.';
    }
}

// send a new message to the server
function sendMessage() {
    if ( receiveReq.readyState == 0 || receiveReq.readyState == 4 ) {
        sendReq.open("POST", 'chatServer.php', true);
        sendReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        // bind function call when state change
        sendReq.onreadystatechange = messageSent;

        var param = "message=ciao";
        sendReq.send(param);

        // reset the content of input
        document.getElementById("message").value = "";
    }
}
```

chatServer.php

```
<?php session_start();
// send headers to prevent caching
header("Expires: Mon, 1 Jul 2000 08:00:00 GMT" ); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" ); 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" ); 
header("Pragma: no-cache" );

// open database
$file_db = new PDO('sqlite:chatdb.sqlite') or die("cannot open database");

if ($file_db) {
    print_r($_POST); // this prints an empty array!!!

    // check if a message was sent to the server
    if (isset($_POST["message"]) && $_POST["message"] != '') {
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        // do stuff
    }
}


?>
```

EDIT:

Updated function, still not working

```
function sendMessage() {
    if( sendReq ){
        /* set the listener now for the response */
        sendReq.onreadystatechange=function(){
            /* Check for the request Object's status */
            if( sendReq.readyState==4 ) {
                if( sendReq.status==200 ){
                    /* Process response here */
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    getUnreadMessages();
                }
            }
        };

        /* Open & send request, outwith the listener */
        sendReq.open( "POST", 'chatServer.php', true );
        sendReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        var param = 'message=ciao';
        sendReq.send( param );
        document.getElementById("message").value = "";
        // relocate to php page for debugging purposes
        window.location.replace("chatServer.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: By using `window.location.replace` you send the request but don't wait for the answer - instead you load the php script instead - that will not work. Use the console to see what is happening in the ajax request.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what was happening.
The POST was working but I was testing it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sendMessage` function is not quite right - have a look at this to see if it helps.

In the original the function checked for the status of `receiveReq` which does not refer to the instantiated XMLHttpRequest Object `sendReq` - also, the request would never get sent even if it had used `sendReq` because the `open` and `send` call was within the code block that checked the response...

```
var sendReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

function messageSent( response ){
    console.info(response);
}

function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else { 
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Status: Error while creating XmlHttpRequest Object.';
    }
}

/* 
   Set the `param` as a parameter to the function, can reuse it more easily.
*/

function sendMessage( param ) {
    if( sendReq ){
        /* set the listener now for the response */
        sendReq.onreadystatechange=function(){
            /* Check for the request Object's status */
            if( sendReq.readyState==4 ) {
                if( sendReq.status==200 ){
                    /* Process response here */
                    messageSent.call( this, sendReq.response );
                } else {
                    /* there was an error */
                }
            }
        };

        /* Open & send request, outwith the listener */
        sendReq.open( "POST", 'chatServer.php', true );
        sendReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        sendReq.send( param );
        document.getElementById("message").value = "";
    }
}

/* send some messages */
sendMessage('message=ciao');
sendMessage('message=ajax...sent via POST');
```

Originally missed the param var declaration so corrected that.

**update**

```
chatserver.php (example)
------------------------
<?php
    /*
        demo_chatserver.php
    */
    session_start();

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /*
            include your db connection
            set your headers
        */



        if( isset( $_POST['message'] ) && !empty( $_POST['message'] ) ){
            @ob_clean();

            /* Create the db conn && test that it is OK */

            /* for the purposes of the tests only */
            $_POST['date']=date( DATE_COOKIE );
            echo json_encode( $_POST, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
            exit();
        }
    }
?>



html / php page
---------------
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>ajax tests</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var sendReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
            function messageSent( response ){
                console.info( 'This is the response from your PHP script: %s',response );
                if( document.getElementById("message") ) document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=response;
            }
            function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
                if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
                    return new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else if( window.ActiveXObject ) {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } else { 
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Status: Error while creating XmlHttpRequest Object.';
                }
            }
            /* 
               Set the `param` as a parameter to the function, can reuse it more easily.
            */
            function sendMessage( param ) {
                if( sendReq ){
                    /* set the listener now for the response */
                    sendReq.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        /* Check for the request Object's status */
                        if( sendReq.readyState==4 ) {
                            if( sendReq.status==200 ){
                                /* Process response here */
                                messageSent.call( this, sendReq.response );
                            } else {
                                /* there was an error */
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    /* Open & send request, outwith the listener */

                    /*NOTE: I have this in a folder called `test`, hence the path below!! */
                    sendReq.open( "POST", '/test/demo_chatserver.php', true );
                    sendReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    sendReq.send( param );
                    if( document.getElementById("message") ) document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
                }
            }
            /* send some data - including original 'message=ciao' but other junk too */
            window.onload=function(event){
                sendMessage('message=ciao&id=23&banana=yellow&php=fun&method=post&evt='+event);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <output id='message' style='display:block;width:80%;float:none;margin:5rem auto;padding:1rem;box-sizing:content-box;border:1px solid black;'>
            <!--
                Expect to see content appear here....
            -->
        </output>
    </body>
</html>


Should output something like:-
------------------------------
{"message":"ciao","id":"23","banana":"yellow","php":"fun","method":"post","evt":"[object Event]","time":1446730182,"date":"Thursday, 05-Nov-15 13:29:42 GMT"}
```

Comment: curious about the downvote, the request gets sent which has corrected the issue the OP had... nevermind - haters gonna hate

Comment: You probably got downvoted because you should explain why your solution works and what you did.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Besides the typo, I also modified the structure of my function to match your structure, thank you for the explanation.
The problem is that still it is not working, and my php page is not able to correctly receive the $_POST variable.
I'm updating the op to let you have a look at my updated code

Answer (score 1):

Here I will show how I send/receive Ajax requests for basic CRUD (Create, Read, Delete, Update) applications and you can implement it in your code.

First of all simple form with input elements in HTML

```
<form action="controller.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password"/>
    <input type="Submit" value="Log In" onclick="logIn(); return false;"/>
</form>
```

After that we write JavaScript function that uses formData object and with AJax technique sends request:

```
function logIn()
{
    //Creating formData object
    var formData = new FormData();
    //Getting input elements by their classNames
    var formElements = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
    //Append form elements to formData object
    for(var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++)
        formData.append(formElements[i].name, formElements[i].value)
    //Creating XMLHttpRequest Object
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            { 
                alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "controller.php"); 
        xmlHttp.send(formData);
}
```